# DocumentNode.SelectNodes return null

Tags: c#, xpath, html-agility-pack

I was wondering if you could explain to me what's wrong in my script. My string "temperature" return always "null".
I'm using the HtmlAgilityPack. What i would like to do is to get the temperature from my friend website's.

my code

```css
private void temperatureBtn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            string url = "http://perso.numericable.fr/meteo-kintzheim/";
            HtmlWeb web = new HtmlWeb();
            HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument doc = web.Load(url);

            string temperature = doc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("/html/body/table[1]/tbody/tr[5]/td[3]/b[2]/font")[0].InnerText;

            MessageBox.Show(temperature.ToString());
        }
```

I would be really grateful if someone could help me :D

Comment: Try to load `string url = "http://perso.numericable.fr/meteo-kintzheim/corps.html";` as the document you are currently loading is a frameset referencing various frames.

Comment: If you view the source of the above link, it's made up of a frameset of different URLs.

Comment: Thx for your answers. I've tried `string url = "http://perso.numericable.fr/meteo-kintzheim/current.html";` but it dosen't work anymore. Is my xpath the problem ?

Comment: I think(I might be wrong) tjat instead of "/" you should use "//" un 'SelectNodes()'

Comment: Sorry but it dosen't work to ^^ I think it's because there is no `[@id="something"]` no ?

Comment: 'tbody' does not exist as an element in /current.html, so remove `tbody` from your XPath and it should work :)

Comment: OMG thank you !!! It finally work <3 How can i add you some reputation ? :D

Comment: Heh. Let me put it as an answer...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

http://perso.numericable.fr/meteo-kintzheim/ is actually a frameset of different frames.

Change the URL to http://perso.numericable.fr/meteo-kintzheim/current.html (the frame you want) and change your XPath from:

```
string temperature = doc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("/html/body/table[1]/tbody/tr[5]/td[3]/b[2]/font")[0].InnerText;
```

To:

```
var temperature = doc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("/html/body/table[1]/tr[5]/td[3]/b[2]/font")[0].InnerText;
```

Omitting `tbody` as it's not part of the document.